# Car Sales & Car Theft (Stolen Automobiles) Data

Tags: data-request, transportation, analysis

Is there open data on car sales by make and model by year? The news has been reporting Honda Accord as the number 1 stolen car in the US, but also wanted to see if this compared with car sales data if the ranking would be any different. Is there open data for both types of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For the USA, the National Highway Traffic Safety Administration (NHTSA) has [general information and fact sheets about theft](http://www.nhtsa.gov/theft) as well as [a search tool](http://www.nhtsa.gov/apps/jsp/theft/index.htm) where you can get theft rates by year, production rates by year, look by manufacturer, and more. Unfortunately, it looks like data is only up to 2011 but it does go back to 1983.
- For more USA data and aggregated info, check out the [National Insurance Crime Bureau (see the 'Theft and Fraud Awareness' menu)](https://www.nicb.org/theft_and_fraud_awareness) which does seem to possibly be the source for [the Honda Accord data point](https://www.nicb.org/theft_and_fraud_awareness/top-vehicles-stolen-by-state).
- Interpol has [some international data](http://www.interpol.int/Crime-areas/Vehicle-crime/Vehicle-crime)

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. This is the link many news articles are referencing: https://www.nicb.org/newsroom/nicb_campaigns/hot%E2%80%93wheels/hot-wheels-2013

Comment: When I click on the PDF for Yearly Theft Data, http://www.nhtsa.gov/theft , it shows number stolen and number manufactured. It is not technically sales, but it does provide a more accurate picture in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

It's not offered as open data, but GoodCarBadCar.net has an [interactive feature](http://www.goodcarbadcar.net/2011/01/toyota-corolla-sales-figures.html) that allows selection of manufacturer and model and delivers annual sales data back to 2002 and monthly back to 2009, separately for US and Canada. It might not be too hard to write a web scraper to get this data.  They also have individual stories which may have the data you need, like this [example](http://www.goodcarbadcar.net/2014/09/august-2014-ytd-usa-all-cars-sales-figures-rankings-results.html).

Here's [one (paid) source for sales by model, 2009-2013](http://wardsauto.com/datasheet/us-vehicle-sales-model-2009-2013).

By manufacturer, a few sources have sales downloadable as XLS: [Edmunds](http://www.edmunds.com/industry-center/data/sales-by-make.html), [Motor Intelligence](http://www.motorintelligence.com/m_frameset.html)

@skram has already covered theft data.